# Is there any $C^\infty$ monotonically non-decreasing function $f$ which satisfies the conditions below?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives, problem-solving

As stated in the above title, is there any  $C^\infty$ monotonically non-decreasing function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that  $f((-\infty, -2]) = \{-1\}, f([2, \infty)) = \{1\}$ and $f(x) = x $ near $0$?

[My approach to this problem for now]

It is well-known that if you define $a: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $a(t) = e^{-\frac{1}{t}} (t > 0), a(t) = 0 (t \leq 0)$, $a$ is $C^\infty$ function.
So, when you define $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $g(t) = \frac{a(t)}{a(t) + a(1-t)}$, you can easily see that $g$ is $C^\infty$ monotonically non-decreasing function such that $g((-\infty, 0]) = \{0\}, g([1, \infty)) = \{1\}$.
If you define $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}; t \mapsto g(t) - g(-t)$, $h$ is $C^\infty$ monotonically non-decreasing function such that $h((-\infty, -2]) = \{-1\}, h([2, \infty)) = \{1\}$. However, it seems that 「$h(t) = t$ in $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$」does not hold for any $\epsilon > 0$. How can I go any further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
g(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \text{if} & x\le 0,\\
\mathrm{e}^{-1/x^2} & \text{if} & x>0.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then it is not hard to show that $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$.

Next, set
$$
h(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x g(t-¼)g(t+¼)\,dt.
$$
Then $h\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$, and $h(x)>0$ if $x>-¼$, while $h$ is constant, for $x\ge ¼$. Say $h(¼)=a>0$.

Next, set $j(x)=h(x+½)h(½-x)/a$. Note that the support of $j$ is

A sought for function could be one of the form
$$
f(x)=-1+c\int_{-\infty}^x j(t)\,dt,
$$
for a suitable $c>0$. In fact,
$$
c\int_{-\infty}^x j(t)\,dt=2.
$$

Comment: I don't know if your solution itself is correct, but thanks to you, I came up with my own solution. Thank you for your reply.